# FSL - Select Files Button Not Working for Multiple Photo Upload on IOS device as a part of Screen File Upload compoent

Tags: visual-workflow, fileupload, field-service-lightning

I am using FSL Mobile Flow, to upload multiple files but in IOS Device I have facing an issue with the 'Select File' Button it's not taking photos from a file manager, the screen gets loading every time. On an Android device, everything works fine. Please help me if someone has this issue.

[image]